# Woocommerce cart refreshing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I recently changed my gateway plugin to **WooCommerce Authorize.Net AIM Gateway** and having issues processing telephone orders.The page now refreshes. We previously used **Authorize.Net CIM for WooCommerce** plugin but had to change it for our fraud protection services.

I am receiving the error:
    (index):1244 Uncaught ReferenceError: SV_WC_Payment_Form_Handler is not 
    defined
    at HTMLDocument. ((index):1244)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)

We currently use **WooCommerce Shop as Customer** for our customer service reps to shop as the customer and process the order.

Thank you! I appreciate any help